# Posting a nested object from Angular to Spring REST API is always null

Tags: java, angular, typescript, rest, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application running in the back-end and an Angular web front-end. Making GET requests to the server returns nested objects correctly, which I can traverse and display on the web page. However, when making a POST request using a form, the server always identifies the nested object as null, even though I pass the same nested object back without any changes.

Java (Example code): Both classes have Simple JPA Repositories

ObjectA.java

```
@Entity
public class ObjectA {
  @ApiModelProperty(hidden=true)
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;
  private String description;
  private ObjectB objectB;
}
```

ObjectB.java

```
@Entity
public class ObjectB {
  @ApiModelProperty(hidden=true)
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;
  private String description;
}
```

Angular (Example code):

ObjectA.ts:

```
import {ObjectB} from './ObjectB';

export class ObjectA {
  constructor(
    public description: string,
    public objectB: ObjectB
  ){}
}
```

ObjectB.ts:

```
export class ObjectB {
  constructor(
    public description: string,
  ){}
}
```

ObjectA.service.ts:

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders({
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('foobar:password')});

...
public save(objA: ObjectA) {
  return this.http.post(this.url, objA, {headers});
}
```

JSON that is passed from the client to the server:

```
{
  "description": "A",
  "objectB": {
    "description": "B"
    "_links": {
      "self": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/objectBs/1"
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

I have custom validation at the back-end which checks the incoming object before persisting any changes to the database. The validation identifies the nested object as null and returns a HTTP Status code of 400 back to the client, along with the custom validation error message "Object B is required".

Comment: have you debugged whether the data is received or not in the controller?

Comment: Post controller code as well

Comment: @varman At the front-end I log both the outgoing object from the form, and its JSON to the web console and can see that the nested object is there. But when I debug the validator, all the data is there except the nested object.

Comment: Show the controller as well

Answer (score 0):

I can't leave comments, so post as an answer. 
It looks like you send wrong **Content-Type** http header. I guess you send `Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8`, but your back-end expects `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but the API actually expects `JSON`, not `multipart/form-data`. I shall edit the question to include the headers I am sending.